# Como realizar validação de dados utilizando yup com locale customizado?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando adicionar validação de dados de entrada a um pequeno script que construi utilizando Express, a parte de validação está utilizando Yup.

Estou com dificuldade para organizar as coisas tendo em vista que surgiu a necessidade de trabalhar com um locale customizado no Yup.

Neste arquivo tenho a definição das mensagens customizadas, bem como uma função que gera um array contendo dados da violação de regra:

```
const yup = require('yup')

yup.setLocale({
    mixed: {
        default: 'é inválido',
        required: 'é um campo obrigatório',
        oneOf: 'deve ser um dos seguintes valores: ${values}',
        notOneOf: 'não pode ser um dos seguintes valores: ${values}',
    },
    string: {
        length: 'deve ter exatamente ${length} caracteres',
        min: 'deve ter pelo menos ${min} caracteres',
        max: 'deve ter no máximo ${max} caracteres',
        email: 'tem o formato de e-mail inválido',
        url: 'deve ter um formato de URL válida',
        trim: 'não deve conter espaços no início ou no fim.',
        lowercase: 'deve estar em maiúsculo',
        uppercase: 'deve estar em minúsculo',
    },
    number: {
        min: 'deve ser no mínimo ${min}',
        max: 'deve ser no máximo ${max}',
        lessThan: 'deve ser menor que ${less}',
        moreThan: 'deve ser maior que ${more}',
        notEqual: 'não pode ser igual à ${notEqual}',
        positive: 'deve ser um número posítivo',
        negative: 'deve ser um número negativo',
        integer: 'deve ser um número inteiro',
    },
        date: {
        min: 'deve ser maior que a data ${min}',
        max: 'deve ser menor que a data ${max}',
    },
        array: {
        min: 'deve ter no mínimo ${min} itens',
        max: 'deve ter no máximo ${max} itens',
    },
});

const validate = (schema, data) => {
    return schema.validate(data, { abortEarly: false })
      .then(_ => {
          return null
      }).catch(err => {
        return err.inner.map(item => {
            return {
                path: item.path,
                message: item.message,
                label: item.params.label
            }
        })
    })
}

module.exports = { yup, validate }
```

Aqui é onde realizado a chamada do arquivo indicado acima:

```
const express = require('express')
const {yup, validate} = require('./validator')

const server = express()

server.use(express.json())
server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}))

server.get('/', async (req, res) => {

      schema = yup.object().shape({
        name: yup.string().email().required(),
        password: yup.string().required()
      });

      const errors = await validate(schema, req.body)

      if (errors) {
          return res.json(errors)
      }

      return res.json({ sucess: true})


})

server.listen(3000)
```

Na minha visão estou fazendo isso de forma errada, porém, não consigo determinar se tenho que separar responsabilidades, utilizar constantes para armazenar a lista de mensagens customizadas e a função validate ou até mesmo um Singleton.

Considerando que nem todas as rotas da aplicação farão input de dados, como eu poderia tratar essa questão da separação de responsabilidades?

Comment: Cara, eu realmente acho que o Yup não suporta esse tipo de coisa... Você pode formatar o erro enviando chaves para o cliente (como se fossem códigos) e ele se responsabiliza de traduzir cada chave para o determinado idioma. Você também pode procurar outra biblioteca de validação...

Answer (score 1):

Eu recomendaria você colocar em arquivos separados o locale customizado, a função de validação e cada schema.

No seu arquivo de rotas, você pode adicionar um middleware chamando a sua função de validação antes de executar a lógica daquela rota. Desta forma, como ele é opcional, não será necessário em todas as rotas.

Fiz um pequeno exemplo com duas rotas, uma sem validação e outra com validação.

Arquivo src/index.js

```
const server = require("./server");
server.listen(3000 || process.env.PORT);
```

Arquivo src/server.js.

```
const express = require("express");
const Youch = require("youch");

class App {
  constructor() {
    this.express = express();
    this.isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
    this.middlewares();
    this.routes();
    this.exception();
  }

  middlewares() {
    this.express.use(express.json());
  }
  routes() {
    this.express.use(require("./routes"));
  }
  // Quando o middleware tem quatro parametros ele serve para tratativa de erros
  exception() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      //
    }
    this.express.use(async (err, req, res, next) => {

      // Apenas para debug no ambiente interno
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
        // Não se aplica
        console.log("producao");
      } else {
        console.log("desenvolvimento");
        const youch = new Youch(err, req);
        return res.json(await youch.toJSON());
      }

      // Para um erro que nao recebeu um tratamento especifico
      return res
        .status(err.status || 500)
        .json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
    });
  }
}

module.exports = new App().express;
```

Arquivo src/routes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const handle = require("express-async-handler");
const routes = express.Router();
const controllers = require("./app/controllers");
const validators = require("./app/validators");
routes.get("/", (req, res) => res.json({ ok: true }));

routes.post(
  "/login",
  async function(req, res, next) {
    await validators.validate(validators.Login, req.body, res, next);
  },
  handle(controllers.SessionController.index)
);

module.exports = routes;
```

Perceba que na rota /login eu tenho 3 parâmetros, o primeiro é o endereço da rota, o segundo é uma função assíncrona que vai chamar a sua rotina de validação, e o terceiro é outra função assíncrona que vai executar a lógica da rota (o express-async-handler serve para facilitar a chamada de uma função de forma assíncrona)

Dentro das pastas /src/app/controllers e /src/app/validators eu tenho um arquivo index.js com apenas uma linha.

```
module.exports = require("require-dir")();
```

Dentro de /src/app/controllers eu tenho um arquivo SessionController.js com a lógica da rota /login.

```
class SessionController {
  async index(req, res) {
    console.log("rota de login!");
    const { name, password } = req.body;
    //Logica para validar o login
    const user = { nome: "User1", email: "teste@teste.com.br" };
    return res.status(200).json({ user, token: "123456" });
  }
}

module.exports = new SessionController();
```

Toda a lógica de validação ficou dentro da pasta /src/app/validators. O seu validator e o schema não tiveram alterações, foram apenas colocados em separado.

Arquivo /src/app/validators/validator.js

```
const yup = require("yup");

yup.setLocale({
  mixed: {
    default: "é inválido",
    required: "é um campo obrigatório",
    oneOf: "deve ser um dos seguintes valores: ${values}",
    notOneOf: "não pode ser um dos seguintes valores: ${values}"
  },
  string: {
    length: "deve ter exatamente ${length} caracteres",
    min: "deve ter pelo menos ${min} caracteres",
    max: "deve ter no máximo ${max} caracteres",
    email: "tem o formato de e-mail inválido",
    url: "deve ter um formato de URL válida",
    trim: "não deve conter espaços no início ou no fim.",
    lowercase: "deve estar em maiúsculo",
    uppercase: "deve estar em minúsculo"
  },
  number: {
    min: "deve ser no mínimo ${min}",
    max: "deve ser no máximo ${max}",
    lessThan: "deve ser menor que ${less}",
    moreThan: "deve ser maior que ${more}",
    notEqual: "não pode ser igual à ${notEqual}",
    positive: "deve ser um número posítivo",
    negative: "deve ser um número negativo",
    integer: "deve ser um número inteiro"
  },
  date: {
    min: "deve ser maior que a data ${min}",
    max: "deve ser menor que a data ${max}"
  },
  array: {
    min: "deve ter no mínimo ${min} itens",
    max: "deve ter no máximo ${max} itens"
  }
});

module.exports = yup;
```

Arquivo /src/app/validators/Login.js

```
const yup = require("./validator");

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup
    .string()
    .email()
    .required(),
  password: yup.string().required()
});
module.exports = schema;
```

A sua função de validação teve alterações para poder ser inserido como um middleware das rotas

Arquivo /src/app/validators/validate.js

```
const validate = (schema, data, res, next) => {
  return schema
    .validate(data, { abortEarly: false })
    .then(_ => {
      next();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      var erro = err.inner.map(item => {
        return {
          path: item.path,
          message: item.message,
          label: item.params.label
        };
      });
      res.send(erro);
    });
};

module.exports = validate;
```

O package.json ficou da seguinte forma:

```
{
  "name": "validacao_yup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node src/index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.1.4",
    "require-dir": "^1.2.0",
    "youch": "^2.0.10",
    "yup": "^0.28.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Achei elegante a sua solução, não compreendi o porque negativaram sua resposta.